# How to get info from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem where I can't get information from a second form in C#.

I made a easy program to add some names to a `ListView`. And somehow I can't get the name from second form.

Form 2:

```
// this is second form
private String name { get; set; }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    name = textBox1.Text;

    this.Close();
}
```

Form 1:

```
// and first form on button click AddPerson()
Form2 basicPerson = new Form2();
basicPerson.ShowDialog();

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(basicPerson.Name);
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

With this code, result I am getting is `ListViewItem` with "Form2" name. Does `.Close();` somehow kill the `Name` variable? How to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `basicPerson.Name` is not the same as the `basicPerson.name`.

C# is case-sensitive.

The `basicPerson.Name` is the [`Control.Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name) (the `Form` class descends from the `Control` class). And the `Control.Name` indeed returns a form name.

Read the `basicPerson.name`. Though you better change the property name to avoid future misunderstandings.

And once you switch to `name` (or to a better property name), you will find out that you need to change an [accessibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) of the property to `public` or `internal` to be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The name property is declared `private`, which means other classes cannot access it. You should change it to `public` or `internal` (accessible by other classes within the same project).

Besides that, you're trying to access `Name` instead of `name`, and C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've got several problems, but nothing complex:

#### Variable scope

There are some scope keywords in C# which handle weither properties and fields (variables) are visible from outside the class. Those are e.g. `public` or `private`. To use the advantages of different scopes is an important aspect of object oriented programming. - [*MSDN Variable and Method Scopes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

#### Concerning your code

You've declared a property called `name`. It's scope is `private`, so you will **not** be able to call it from outside the `Form2` class. If you want to access `name`'s value, you should change it to `public`. If you want to ensure, that `name`' value can be read but not changed from outside code, please change the `set-accessor` to a private one.

```
public string PersonName { get; private set; }
```

Like you have seen, I changed your property's name. This has 2 main reasons:

1. In C#, property names should be uppercase by code convention. - [*C# naming convention*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. `Name` is already a property of your `Form2` class. This could be disturbing. - [*MSDN Form class*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx)

Last but not least, there's a little typo in your code.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(basicPerson.Name); // <-- "Name" should be "name"
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(basicPerson.PersonName); // If you want to use my approach...
```